# Blinking Cursor After "Enable Networking" in Recovery Mode and unable to do anything else.

Tags: recovery-mode

After hitting "Yes" on "Do you wish to continue?" I get

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 166400/2444624 files, 906859/9765755 blocks
```

With a blinking cursor on the line below it. From here, the only thing I can do is power off and start up again, and I'm still in read-only mode.

Background:

I'm using a Toshiba Portege R100, a laptop that lacks a CD drive and can't boot from a USB stick.

I removed the R100's hard disc, plugged it into a Mac (over USB) that was in "Try Ubuntu" mode using a DVD,and then I installed Ubuntu onto the R100's hard disk.

With the hard disk back in the R100, on start-up, after the GRUB menu, with Ubuntu selected, it displays the Ubuntu logo then goes into "Low-Graphics Mode," covered here:
[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/141607#141607)

In attempting to try the various fixes reported there, I have to use Recovery Mode, which leaves the disk, by default, in read-only mode.

And that's where I try "Enable Networking," which results in the blinking cursor (crash?).

I have also tried dropping to the shell and trying
    `# mount -o rw,remount /`

which is the fix here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870817

But that doesn't work. I just get a new prompt, as if I entered a return, and the system remains read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, VedVals. The code blocks make this much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another (better) answer, is that for the Enable Networking command, you have Network access. Who would have thought? ; ) So, when in the terminal, get hard-wired-in, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have no idea why this works, but it does. To recover from Low-Graphics Mode into a working terminal with the disk set in rw mode, if Ctrl-Alt-F1 gets you a blue screen:

On boot, choose Advanced Options from the GRUB menu

Choose Recovery Mode

When the menu appears, choose Resume Normal Boot

{Low-Graphics Mode}

THEN Ctrl-Alt-F1 works fine, then login.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands by activating the root shell:

```
ifconfig eth0 up 
dhclient eth0
```

Comment: Well, this is for enabling the Ethernet wired connection.